# Which check would be best for deciding which personality of a multiple-personality character is in control?

Tags: dnd-5e, player-characters

My brother wants to play a character with multiple personalities but we're unsure how to actually go about switching which personality is in control.

The system he currently has is this:

> Every 1d6 hours, do a Wisdom check for the inactive personality, and a Wisdom save for active personality.  If active personality fails save, inactive personality becomes the active personality.

I'm under the impression that there is probably a different save/check that would be better for this, but I can't think of what it might be.

The DM already knows about this character concept and has given the OK to do it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Comment: This may be of interest to your GM and brother: [Roleplaying a multiple personality character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62479/roleplaying-a-multiple-personality-character)

Comment: When the personality changes, does anything else change along with it? For example mental stats, class features, or skill proficiencies, etc. Also, could you elaborate what you mean by "better"? The answers so far have assumed that "better" means "most similar to other uses of the same saves", but it could mean other things, for example "most likely to result in a successful save".

Answer (score 5):

General rule of thumb for saving throws, From the DMG pg. 238

**Saving Throws**

**Strength**: Opposing a force that would physically move or bind you

**Dexterity**: Dodging out of harm's way

**Constitution**: Enduring a disease, poison or other hazard that saps vitality

**Intelligence**: Disbelieving certain illusions and resisting mental assaults that can be refuted with logic, sharp memory, or both

**Wisdom**: Resisting effects that charm, frighten, or otherwise assault your willpower

**Charisma**: Withstanding effects, such as possession, that would subsume your personality or hurl you to another plane of existence

You seem to be describing an effect similar to possession or the subsumption of personality, and as such I would suggest Charisma saves as being the most relevant check/save.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Charisma would be better choice I think. It is generally the save used vs. possession and generally for effects that stop a character being itself.

Changing every 1d6 hours could be a problem as that means it will occur during sleep time. One alternative to consider - whenever the character is faced with a situation and an inactive personality thinks it could do a better job, have a contested charisma check to see if it can take over.

Comment: That does seem good, but I'll hold out on accepting it so that others can give an answer